# change row colour based on text

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey guys im stuck on this. Just trying to change the row colour based on cell text value. this is what i have at the moment

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
                    string value = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"Field1"));

                    if (value == "Complete")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#c6efce");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code ???any exception or error???

Comment: Ehm, is this C# or ASP Classic? The two are mutually exclusive!

Answer (score 0):

`Color.FromName` method requires a color name and you are passing hexadecimal color value,  replace it with this:

```
using System.Drawing;
...  
e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32("c6efce", 16));
```

OR

```
e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c6efce");
```