# In VB.net How to colour different rows in a dataGridView with different colours based on different conditions

Tags: vb.net

My Code is something like this:
I am just a bignner and I am unable to make this code work for me.please help me

```
Private Sub dgvOrdersData_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvOrdersData.CellFormatting
    If e.RowIndex <> dgvOrdersData.NewRowIndex Then
        If e.ColumnIndex = dgvOrdersData.Columns("CashOrCredit").Index Then
            If e.Value.ToString = "Credit" Then
                dgvOrdersData.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Else
                dgvOrdersData.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Nothing
            End If
        End If

    If e.ColumnIndex = dgvOrdersData.Columns("Job").Index Then
            If e.Value.ToString = "PendingJob" Then
                dgvOrdersData.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            Else
                dgvOrdersData.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Nothing
            End If
        End If

    If e.ColumnIndex = dgvOrdersData.Columns("Job").Index AND e.ColumnIndex = dgvOrdersData.Columns("CashOrCredit").Index Then
            If e.Value.ToString = "PendingJob & Credit " Then
                dgvOrdersData.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink
            Else
                dgvOrdersData.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Nothing
            End If
        End If


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: After you read [Ask] and take the [Tour], [edit] your question to clarify what "unable to make this code work" means

Comment: This might be help full, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781302/change-row-colour-based-on-text